# sqrt() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python

```
    def sqrt (n, one):
        floating_point_precision = 10*16
        n_float = float(( n * floating_point_precision) // one) / floating_point_precision
        x = (int(floating_point_precision * math.sqrt(n_float)) * one) // floating_point_precision
        n_one = n * one
        while 1:
            x_old = x
            x = ( x + n_one // x) // 2
            if x == x_old:
                return x

print "The newton estimate of", mynum, "is", sqrt(mynum)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Brett/Desktop/Python/squareroot.py", line 21, in <module>
    print "The newton estimate of", mynum, "is", sqrt(mynum)
TypeError: sqrt() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: You won't get many answers if you post code without a question.

Comment: Isnt the answer clear? You have a function with 2 arguments, but passing only one in the last line.

Comment: Even without a question, that error is pretty clear-cut.  The function definition has 2 arguments, but you're only passing one.

Comment: It seems you only passed in one parameter, when 2 is required. You can tell by the message `TypeError: sqrt() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Answer (score 3):

Your `sqrt` function has two parameters, but you only provided one argument. It seems that the second argument should be the value "1".

```
print "The newton estimate of", mynum, "is", sqrt(mynum, 1.0)
```

Comment: ok thanks it worked, now it says global name math is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You've defined `sqrt` as a function which takes two arguments. Later, your code references your function: `sqrt`. Try changing  `"/Users/Brett/Desktop/Python/squareroot.py", line 21` to use `math.sqrt`, or provide it with a second argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sqrt()` function takes two arguments, `n` and `one`. In your last line, however, you only pass one argument.

Comment: I am not sure how to fix or what i need to do. I am a beginner

Answer (score 2):

surely its just that you are declaring

```
def sqrt(n,one):
```

which has 2 parameters and the calling it using

```
sqrt(mynum)
```

which is one parameter

Comment: ok but now global name math is not defined in math.sqrt

Comment: then i would suggest that you ask a better formed question with this new problem. or just `import math`